# Dismiss DialogFragment that's instanciated in a Base Activity class

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

My application checks in MainActivity eclusively if Gps is enabled. If not a DialogFragment appears which guides the user to Android Location Settings.

On accessing all Activities a Dialog appears if no network/internet-connection is established or even connecting to a network.

Since this check is necessary in all Activities I've implemented a BaseActivity for all my Activities and implemented the check in onStart().

When the user returns from managing the Location Settings, a second EnableInternetDialogFragment appears. The first (not solved) dialog is still visible

My current solution is to dismiss the dialog in the onPause() method, but this doesn't work well at all.

Is there a way to avoid/manage this behaviour?

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected ConnectivityTester connectivityTester;
    protected ConnectivityHelper connectivityHelper;

    protected EnableInternetDialogFragment enableInternetDialogFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        connectivityTester = new ConnectivityTester();
        connectivityHelper = new ConnectivityHelper();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final boolean internetEnabled = connectivityTester.isInternetEnabled(getApplicationContext());
        if (!internetEnabled) {
            enableInternetDialogFragment = new EnableInternetDialogFragment();
            enableInternetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "enableInternetDialog");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (enableInternetDialogFragment.getDialog() != null) {
            enableInternetDialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }


    public final class EnableInternetDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Activite Network/Internet")
                .setMessage("test")
                .setPositiveButton("Activate Internet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        connectivityHelper.enableMobileInternetSettings(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Activate WiFi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        connectivityHelper.enableWiFiSettings(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                }).create();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I've implemented @Override public void onPause() { super.onPause(); this.dismiss(); } in EnableInternetDialogFragment class.
Works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss your Dialog just before switching to the Wifi settings (on the onClick) :

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Activite Network/Internet")
            .setMessage("test")
            .setPositiveButton("Activate Internet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    connectivityHelper.enableMobileInternetSettings(getApplicationContext());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Activate WiFi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    connectivityHelper.enableWiFiSettings(getApplicationContext());
                }
            }).create();
    }
```

The Dialog will be dismissed then the settings will pop up

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. _BaseActivity_ as an abstract class is called before _MainActivity_ is called. So the GPS-DialogFragment is called after Internet-DialogFragment. Internet-DialogFragment is shown in the background. You have to manage the Gps-Dialog first and then you get back to MainActivity which calls Internet-Dialog the 2nd time.

Comment: Oki, but can you do the same for the GPS Dialog (dismiss it before launching the GPS settings)?

Comment: Sure, but on reentry of _MainActivity_, _BaseActivity_ is called again. The first _InternetDialogFragment_ isn't dismissed till yet. But now a 2nd _InternetDialogFragment_ is shown. --> 1.) BaseActivity calls _InternetDialogFragment_ 2.) MainActivity calls _GpsDialogFragment_ --> _GpsDialogFragment_ is on top 3.) User calls the GpsSettings of Android 4) User returns to MainActivity which calls BaseActivity implicitly --> a 2nd _InternetDialogFragment_ is called.

Comment: Oki I see now (sorry for the long catching), if you check your enableInternetDialogFragment in onStart to see if it's currently not null and / or shown, does it solve your problem ?

Comment: Never mind :-) I solved it. I've implemented `@Override
  public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   this.dismiss();
  }` in _EnableInternetDialogFragment_ class ! I'm not sure if this is a proper solution, but it works fine and I couldn't find any drawbacks till yet

Comment: Yeah should work for your case, if you want to dismiss it whenever the user navigate to another screen